# I have some problem with CoreData Swift in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, observers

I have some problem with NotificationCenter.default.addObserver. The first page I have Note tableView when I click tableView item show this Controller "NoteDetailsViewController". in NoteDetailsViewController I cannot get note instance like this `self.note?.noteCategory //return nil.` P.S. I have saved Note item in Core Data persistentStore.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class NoteDetailsViewController: UIViewController, ManagedObjectContextDependentType {


    var note: Note?
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!


    @IBOutlet weak var noteCategoryLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var fromLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var messageTextView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.NSManagedObjectContextDidSave,
                                               object: nil,
                                               queue: nil,
                                               using:
            {
                (notification: Notification) in
                if let updatedNotes = notification.userInfo?[NSUpdatedObjectsKey] as? Set<Note> {
                    self.note = updatedNotes.first
                   self.setUIValues()
                }
        })

        setUIValues()
    }


    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self,
                                                  name: NSNotification.Name.NSManagedObjectContextDidSave,
                                                  object: nil)

func setUIValues() {
    self.noteCategoryLabel.text = self.note?.noteCategory //this line return nil
    self.messageTextView.text = self.note?.message //this line return nil
    self.fromLabel.text = self.note?.from //this line return nil
}
```

Comment: i want to get employee from NSNotification.Name.NSManagedObjectContextDidSave

Comment: i don't send data first view controller to second viewController. When note updated NSManagedObject context send signal in my app